# Confluence User Macro Broken in Upgrade

Tags: java, macros, jira, confluence

The following user macro worked in Confluence 5.1.  Now it is broken in 5.6.  Only the top query renders.  The other three queries do not render.  Any of the four queries will render only when I delete all of the remaining three.

Has the syntax or coding engine changed from from 5.1 to 5.6?

Here is the code:

```
## @param jiraproject:title=Project|type=string
## @param productversion:title=Version|type=string
Date: $action.dateFormatter.format($content.currentDate)


$action.getHelper().renderConfluence("{jiraissues:url=...}")`


$action.getHelper().renderConfluence("{jiraissues:url=...}")


$action.getHelper().renderConfluence("{jiraissues:url=...}")


$action.getHelper().renderConfluence("{jiraissues:url=...}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some errors there.

Try replacing

```
$action.getHelper().renderConfluence(...)
```

with

```
$action.getHelper().renderConfluenceMacro(...)
```

Alternatively you could use the Confluence storage format and write something similar to this:

```
## @param jiraproject:title=Project|type=string
## @param productversion:title=Version|type=string
Date: $action.dateFormatter.format($content.currentDate)

<ac:macro ac:name="jiraissues">
  <ac:parameter ac:name="title">Some title</ac:parameter>
  <ac:parameter ac:name="url">http://jira.example.com/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/temp/SearchRequest.xml?jqlQuery=project+%3D+${paramjiraproject}+AND+issuetype+%3D+Defect+AND+affectedVersion+%3D+%22${paramproductversion}%22++and+%28fixVersion+is+empty+or+fixVersion+%21%3D+%22${paramproductversion}%22%29+ORDER+BY+priority,Status+DESC&tempMax=1000\|columns=type,priority,key,summary,status,resolution,created,fixVersion\|renderMode=static</ac:parameter>
</ac:macro>
```

See this blogpost for another example user macro that wraps `jiraissues`:

[JIRA Release User Macro for Atlassian Confluence](https://davidsimpson.me/2014/06/23/jira-release-user-macro-atlassian-confluence/)

Comment: David, I am truly grateful for your help.  People like you and others on Stack Overflow is what makes the Internet an invaluable resource.  Atlassian support does not offer support for user macros.  Your suggestion works. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Glad it was helpful & not too cryptic.